# BreezeJS Get Metadata from the server without using Entity Framework for complex objects (nested objects)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

This is my model on the server side. I don't want to use Entity Framework, how would I generate BreezeJS metadata from the server. Breeze Metadata Format found here http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-metadata-format doesn't work.

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<App> Apps { get; set; }
}

public class App
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Info { get; set; }
}
```

Did anyone try complex objects (nested object) similar to above one without using EF.

Using Breeze Metdata API or OData ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example http://www.breezejs.com/samples/nodb it should give you a clue.

Comment: I checked this example, the difference is my example doesn't have so called navigation link between objects the way TodoList and TodoItem entities have in between them. 

I tried creating metadata by using JS metadata API similar to NoDB example but I couldn't get them right. 

For example, I couldn't figure out how Apps property in User object should be defined?